# debug code, not sure why im not getting the right value for x1

Tags: matlab

```
function [x1] = tutorial1(x0,nMax,tol)
% Calculate the root of the function f(x) = x^3 - 3^x + 1
% using the Newton Method of root-finding.
% Inputs: 
%        - x0     initial guess
%        - nMax   number of iterations
%        - tol    solution accuracy tolerance
% Output:
%        - x1     converged root of the equation
% Initialisation of the values x0, nMax, to

x0 = 1.5;
nMax = 15;
tol = 1e-4;

 % for loop acting continously for 15 iterations 
for i = 1:nMax
   fx0= (x0).^3-3.^(x0)+1;
   differentialx0=3.*(x0.^2) - 3.^x0.*log(3);
   %function f(x0)respectively
   x1 = x0 -fx0./differentialx0;

   if abs(x1-x0)<tol
   break
   end 
   x0 = x1; 

   fprintf('Iteration = %d, x0 = %.4f, x1 = %.4f, fx1 = %.4f\n',i,x0,x1);
    end 

 % Sample output code for monitoring (this should be included in your loop structure.


  return
```

[image]

Comment: You could at least take the time to learn how to properly format the code in your post. Also, what is the question? All I see is code. Please read [ask]!

Comment: I apologise this is my first question on this site, i was just wondering this is a question on newtons method, were supposed to get the value of the roots of the equation but im getting the wrong value for x1 and wasnt sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the right value actually. With this kind of method, you are numerically solving an equation. So you will converge to the solution with the precision you want (if it works) set by the tolerance criteria.

Execute the code below. It is the same with more digits for the number printing, and a more strict tolerance, and a print of the error (and I added fx1 computation to print it too).

```
x0 = 1.5;
nMax = 15;
tol = 1e-10; %1e-4

 % for loop acting continously for 15 iterations 
for i = 1:nMax
   fx0= (x0).^3-3.^(x0)+1;
   differentialx0=3.*(x0.^2) - 3.^x0.*log(3);
   %function f(x0)respectively
   x1 = x0 -fx0./differentialx0;
   fx1= (x0).^3-3.^(x0)+1;
   error = abs(x1-x0) ;

   if error<tol
   break
   end 

   x0 = x1; 

   fprintf('Iteration = %i, x0 = %.6f, x1 = %.6f, fx1 = %.6f, error = %.6f \n',i,x0,x1,fx1,error);
    end 

 % Sample output code for monitoring (this should be included in your loop structure.
```

You will get this output in the command :

```
Iteration = 1, x0 = 2.288476, x1 = 2.288476, fx1 = -0.821152, error = 0.788476 
Iteration = 2, x0 = 1.994137, x1 = 1.994137, fx1 = 0.628953, error = 0.294339 
Iteration = 3, x0 = 2.000009, x1 = 2.000009, fx1 = -0.012367, error = 0.005873 
Iteration = 4, x0 = 2.000000, x1 = 2.000000, fx1 = 0.000020, error = 0.000009
```

It gives a solution closer to 2 (yet if you add more digits to fprintf, you will see that it is not a perfect 2 but something like 2.000000000001).

Keep in mind that, if the algorithm converges, it will give you a numerical solution close to theoretical solution with an error which depends on the tolerance you provide